# Need to remove Metasploit from my Ubuntu 12.10 system

Tags: software-uninstall, metasploit

Tonight I installed Metasploit in my Ubuntu 12.10 it did not work properly, so I removed it by executing the following command in terminal

```
sudo rm -r /opt/metasploit
```

Now when i try to re-install it, it says

```
this service script file exists
```

How do I remove it properly?

Comment: how did you uninstall MS